# MobileFirst: Logon to one device that will logout other devices/web

Tags: session, ibm-mobilefirst, device, mobilefirst-server

I have to implement a scenario in which if user login to 2nd device or mobile-web then the first device/web should be logged-out.

Both app & mobile-web are running on the same MobileFirst server and are using the same adapters and having almost same functionality.

I am not sure if such type of provision provided in MFP.

I am open to suggestions or guidance.

Answer (score 1):

MFP doesn't support that. I know some application has similar feature,
I believe it's up to user code.
Would you check this information?

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_oauth_security_model.html

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/voicesw/ps556/products_administration_guide_chapter09186a0080153e60.html

[How to logout previous session of a user,if he logins again on same or different browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416732/how-to-logout-previous-session-of-a-user-if-he-logins-again-on-same-or-different/1416859#1416859)

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jbA-CDEbHowJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/1416732/how-to-logout-previous-session-of-a-user-if-he-logins-again-on-same-or-different+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: Thanks for sharing such valuable links.